# Twilio action in Dial method not working, C#

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-twiml

I have encountered a small problem using Twilio with C#. Basically, I'm having trouble controlling the call after the .Dial method is called.

Considering I have the following piece of code:

```
   TwilioResponse _twiml = new TwilioResponse();
   _twiml.Dial(RedirectPhoneNumner, new { action = Url.Action("BusyCallAction"), timeout = 5 });`
```

The following is being rendered in my application:

```
<Response>
<Dial action="/Home/BusyCallAction" timeout="5">*RedirectPhoneNumber*</Dial>
</Response>
```

For testing purposes, I've added a timeout of **5 seconds**. After the *timeout* has passed, the call ends, instead of redirecting the user to the following controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BusyCallAction(string dialCallStatus)
    {
        if (dialCallStatus == "busy")
        {
            _twiml.Say(dialCallStatus);
            //more code here
        }
        return TwiML(_twiml);
    }
```

Note: The method has the HttpPost data annotation because the default *method* attribute in  the dial method is set to *POST*.

I need to know whether the call was answered, or if it was busy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE:This question was answered by one of Twilio's agents. I told him that he should post the answer here, but he doesnt have an SO account, **yet**.

The solution was indeed quite simple, the code works as expected, but the condition of

```
if (dialCallStatus == "busy")
        {
            _twiml.Say(dialCallStatus);
            //more code here
        }
```

Would never be triggered in this test scenario, as when the **timeout** occurs, the status is "**no-answer**", as specified here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial

Hope this answer helps anyone with the same situation.